# How should I select or display the out variable from a stored procedure call?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm writing a pretty basic stored procedure that just takes values from the sample DB2 database and computes the standard deviation. I wrote the procedure itself just fine, and I can call it without error. But I can't figure out how to actually display my result or select it in a statement. Everything I try results in a syntax error and I haven't been able to find anyone doing this specific task in my google searches.

This is the gist of my code (snipped for brevity):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAL_STD_DEV
  (OUT std_dev real)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
    --do stuff
    SET std_dev = 10; --changed for simplicity
  END@

CALL SAL_STD_DEV(?)@
```

All this runs, but just CALL doesn't create any output. What's the syntax to SELECT the out variable? I can't put a DECLARE before the CALL because it's not in a stored procedure, and PRINT doesn't work either.

(@ is my terminal character because I'm using ; in the stored procedure)

**Edit:** Both the create procedure and call statements are made in the same SQL file, the database is connect to through localhost and I'm using DB2 11.1.0.1527 and developing in IBM Data Studio 4.1.2.

Comment: Might be appropriate to say whence the CALL is being made; if I knew where a PRINT statement was applicable, I might be able to intuit from where the work, i.e. "it", is being performed. Also mention of what variant of DB2 [on what platform] and release is always appropriate in an OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From wherever the CALL is being made, that feature might present a Result Set, despite apparently not presenting the result of an OUT parameter.  If so, then the stored procedure perhaps could be revised to return the OUT value [instead, or additionally] as a result set, so that the interface that accepts the CALL statement as input, might present that result-set.  Regardless:

In a statement processor [e.g. that is not a GUI, but] for which SELECT query output is presented, the following scripted requests should likely suffice:

```
create variable my_real real
;
call SAL_STD_DEV(my_real)
;
select my_real from sysibm.sysdummy1
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked and is satisfactory for my need. I updated my original question to include version information in case someone else has the same question in the future.